# How to hide an ActiveX Command Button when printing a word document?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have an ActiveX Command Button that when pressed opens a userform to allow data entry into the word document. This button needs to remain visible when working on the document but not visible when printing.

How can I hide/make invisible only when printing?

Unlike in Excel VBA where the properties include an option to 'PrintObject', word VBA does not have this functionality. The best I have been able to do is delete the button after being clicked but this is not really what I want.

```
'Needs to hide button only on printing, not delete it

UserForm2.Show
CommandButton1.Select
Selection.Delete
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are having `ActiveX Command Button` in word and using user form entered data gets feed in corresponding fields and you are closing user form and then trying to print document and printed file should not have `ActiveX Command Button` in it

Paste the following code into `CommandButton_Click event`

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 

 With ActiveDocument 
    .Shapes(1).Visible = msoFalse 
    .PrintOut Background:=False 
    .Shapes(1).Visible = msoTrue 
 End With 

End Sub
```

Comment: That is correct, unfortunately when I run this code I get the following Run-time error: "The index into the specified collection is out of bounds." referencing lines 3 and 5 on this code. Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Jakec arun was having to guess how to address the CommandButton on your document surface. The assumption in the code is that it's the first object in the document that has text-wrap fomatting applied. You need to adjust the code to address the correct object. We can't know how to identify it since we don't have the document...

Comment: @CindyMeister The Command Button is the first and only object in the document. I have attempted to specify the object but I continue to get the same error or the error "The item with the specified name wasn't found".  
       _ActiveDocument
            .Shapes("CommandButton1").Visible = msoTrue_

Comment: @JakeC Is the button formatted with text-wrap, or is it inline with the text. If the latter, it would be a member of the `InlineShapes` collection so try `InlineShapes(1)`, instead? Ah, but in that case .Visible won't work, it would have to have `.Range.Font.Hidden = True` to hide it.

Comment: Thanks @CindyMeister! Got it to work using the following code:
   `InlineShapes(1).Range.Font.Hidden = True`
   `ActiveDocument.PrintOut Background:=False`

Answer (score 2):

*@ille P. - You should post a new question, perhaps with a link to this one.*

Try the Shapes collection as well as inlineshape collection.

The following is suggested by Ibby on the [Microsoft Word MVP VBA FAQ pages](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/TblsFldsFms/HidePrintButton.htm):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With ActiveDocument
        .Shapes(1).Visible = msoFalse
        .PrintOut Background:=False
        .Shapes(1).Visible = msoTrue
    End With
End Sub
```

So translating to the collection:

```
Dim oShape as Shape
For Each oShape in ActiveDocument.Shapes
    oShape.Visible = False
Next oShape
```

That would, though hide all shapes, not just your buttons.
You could add bookmarks to your buttons and use them as a filtering Range.

Answer (score 1):

After investigating what happens with the CommandButtons, I detected that in the document they are included (if it has not been edited to be a Shape) in the InLineShape collection by being encapsulated in an InLineShape object.

It would be great if we could directly typecast from CommandButton to InShapeLine but I think Microsoft doesn't allow it, too bad.

The idea is to create two class modules:

- One will be an event manager to capture the 'before printing' event and another.
- The other will be an encapsulation of an InLineShape object that will have the methods to make the object visible, taking advantage of the Brightness property of the PictureFormat object.

**CLASS clsButton**

```vb
Option Explicit

Private M_ishpButton As InlineShape

Public Property Get button() As InlineShape
    Set button = M_ishpButton
End Property

Public Property Set button(oObj As InlineShape)
    Set M_ishpButton = oObj
End Property

Public Property Get Visible() As Boolean
    Visible = Not bIsHidden
End Property

Public Property Let Visible(bValue As Boolean)
    Dim oPictureFormat As PictureFormat
    
    Set oPictureFormat = M_ishpButton.PictureFormat

    If bValue Then
        Call show
    Else
        Call hide
    End If
End Property

Private Function bIsHidden() As Boolean
    Dim oPictureFormat As PictureFormat

    Set oPictureFormat = M_ishpButton.PictureFormat
    
    If oPictureFormat.Brightness = 1 Then bIsHidden = True: Exit Function
    
    bIsHidden = False

End Function

Private Sub hide()
    Dim oPictureFormat As PictureFormat
    
    Set oPictureFormat = M_ishpButton.PictureFormat
    
    oPictureFormat.Brightness = 1
End Sub

Private Sub show()
    Dim oPictureFormat As PictureFormat
    
    Set oPictureFormat = M_ishpButton.PictureFormat
    
    With oPictureFormat
        .Brightness = 0.5
        .Contrast = 0.5
    End With
End Sub
```

**CLASS clsEvents**

```vb
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents appWord As Word.Application
Public WithEvents docWord As Word.Document
Private m_button As New clsButton


Private Sub appWord_DocumentBeforePrint(ByVal Doc As Document, Cancel As Boolean)
   
    'If process is not cancel and button is not visible
    With m_button 
        If Cancel = False And .Visible = True Then
            .Visible = False
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub appWord_WindowDeactivate(ByVal Doc As Document, ByVal Wn As Window)
    
    'If button is not visible then set to true
    With m_button 
        If .Visible = False Then
            .Visible = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Public Property Set button(oObj As clsButton)
    Set m_button = oObj 
End Property
```

**CLASS ThisDocument**
Now, in ThisDocument class should create objects and linking

```vb
Dim oEventsManager As New clsEvents
Dim oEditedButton As New clsButton

Const BUTTON_LINKS As String = "cmdUpdateLinks" 'For example

Dim oInShpDoc As Word.InlineShape, oOleDoc As Word.OLEFormat, oInShapesDoc As Word.InlineShapes

Public Sub Set_Manager_Events()
    Set oEventsManager.appWord = Word.Application 'ThisDocument.Application
    Set oEventsManager.docWord = ThisDocument
    
    Set oInShpDoc = FNC_oGet_Button_Variable(BUTTON_LINKS)


    If Not oInShpDoc Is Nothing Then
        Set oEditedButton.button = oInShpDoc
        Set oEventsManager.button = oEditedButton
    End If
End Sub

'###### EVENTOS OF BUTTON
Private Sub cmdUpdateLinks_Click()

    If oEventsManager.appWord Is Nothing Then Call Set_Manager_Events
    
    Call UpdateLinks ' Is one example
End Sub



Public Function FNC_oGet_Button_Variable(sCodeName As String) As InlineShape

    Dim oForm As InlineShape, oFormsInLine As InlineShapes, oOLEFormat As OLEFormat

    Set oFormsInLine = ThisDocument.InlineShapes

    If oFormsInLine .Count < 1 Then GoTo bye

    i = 0
    For Each oForm In oFormsInLine 

        With oForm 
            Set oOLEFormat = .OLEFormat
        
            If Not oOLEFormat Is Nothing Then

                If InStr(1, oOLEFormat.ClassType, "CommandButton") > 0 Then
                    If .OLEFormat.Object.Name = sCodeName Then
                        Set FNC_oGet_Button_Variable= oForm 
                        Exit Function
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next

bye:
    Set FNC_oGet_Button_Variable = Nothing
End Function
```

With this you will can hide button for printing.